# Setting origin in Gnuplot when in polar/parametric mode

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to draw a circle with an offset, in gnuplot. I can do that by adding the offset in the equations, as shown below. However, I want to do some more complicated rendering, e.g. render multiple circles each with a different angular offset around an offset origin. The script would be much more comprehensive if I do that by changing the origin of each circle's plot.

I am testing with a single circle:

```
set size square
set parametric
set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set trange [0:2*pi]
set multiplot

# circle centered at 0,0
fx(t) = sin(t)
fy(t) = cos(t)
plot fx(t), fy(t)

# circle centered at -1,-1
fx(t) = -1 + sin(t)
fy(t) = -1 + cos(t)
plot fx(t), fy(t)

# can't center this circle properly at 1,1
set origin 0.113, 0.23
fx(t) = sin(t)
fy(t) = cos(t)
plot fx(t), fy(t)
```

To achieve an offset of (1, 1), I have to use an origin of (0.113, 0.233). So, what is the equation that gives these coordinates? I have tried various sin/cos combinations since this might be related to polar coordinates, but no lack. The same exact situation occurs when using polar mode instead of parametric mode.

Answer (score 1):

Check the online help about `origin`, it is a display option and not a plotting option.

There is no reason why this shouldn't work else. You can take inspiration from this code:

```
CENTER_X="1.5 3.2 -2.4"
CENTER_Y="-2.3 1.2 -0.4"
ANGLE="0 45 180"
RADIUS="1 1.2 0.8"
set parametric
set angle degrees
set trange [0:315]
set xrange [-6:6]
set yrange [-6:6]
set size ratio -1
set multiplot
unset key
do for [i=1:words(CENTER_X)] {
 plot word(CENTER_X,i)+word(RADIUS,i)*cos(word(ANGLE,i)+t),word(CENTER_Y,i)+word(RADIUS,i)*sin(word(ANGLE,i)+t)
}
unset multiplot
```